# Duplicate jobs are being generated in DAG for the same action in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark-streaming job in which I receive data from a message queue and process a bunch of records. In the process, I have a **take()** method on a dataset. Although the **take** action is happening in an expected manner, In the DAG visualization, I see multiple job ids created and all of them have the same **take action**. This is happening only when the data is in the order of a hundreds of thousand records. I didn't observe redundant jobs while running with tens of records in my local machine. Can anyone help me understand the reasoning behind this behavior?

[image: DAG]

The job ids - (91 to 95) are basically running the same **action**. Following is the code snippet corresponding to the mentioned action above.

```
val corruptedMessageArray: Array[ String ] = corruptedMessageDs.take(1);
    if ( !corruptedMessageArray.isEmpty ) {
        val firstCorruptedMessage: String = corruptedMessageArray( 0 )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be whether duplicate jobs are created by Spark.

If you look at the screenshot you will see that the jobs have a different number of tasks, hence it is not a simple matter of duplication.

I am not sure exactly what is happening, but it seems that for large datasets `take()` needs several quick subsequent jobs. Perhaps because it devises work, or perhaps because it needs to try how much work needs to be done.

Comment: Yes, just realized that the jobs performing the same action, are having a different number of tasks.

Comment: But still, that would not explain why multiple jobs itself are needed for performing one "action"

Comment: I'm observing the same behavior. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Mazar My post contains the best estimate of an answer that I could find. If this does not apply to your case, consider asking a new question. (Make sure to refer to this one, and indicate what additional challenges you face/how your situation is different).